# How do I implement my ImageManager?

Tags: c++, class, instance

I'm having trouble understanding the implementation of an image manager. I built one based off of [this tutorial](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Image-Manager) and it works great in itself, but I have no idea how to use it. In my tic tac toe game, I have an engine class which is self explanatory, a Board class which holds the game board (which has only one image) and a Box class, which has two possible images (X or an O), and then the ImageManager class from the tutorial (code to follow). I want to have just one instance of my ImageManager in my Game Engine, then instances of other classes such as my board and boxes can efficiently pull their images from the ImageManager. However, I have had no luck with making an ImageManager instance inside my Engine class. Here's how I have gone about this:

Engine.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "ImageManager.h"
#include "Board.h"

class Engine{
public:
    Engine();
    ~Engine();

    void Go();

    ImageManager &GetManager();
private:
    void ProcessInput();
    void Update();
    void Render();

    void FillVector();

    ImageManager imgr;

    Board board;

    sf::Sprite gameBoard;

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::Event event;
};
```

So now I have my instance of ImageManager, and an accessor method so that any other class can retrieve it, like so:

Board.h

```
#include "Box.h"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "ImageManager.h"
#include "Engine.h"

class Board{
public:
    Board();
    ~Board();

    std::vector<Box> &GetBoxes();

    sf::Sprite GetGameBoard();
private:
    sf::Sprite gameBoard;

    Engine e;

    std::vector<Box> boxes;
};
```

Board.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Board.h"

Board::Board(){
    e.GetManager().AddResourceDirectory("images/");
    //error checking, images/ is indeed in the vector
    //std::cout << imgr.GetResourceDirectory()[0];

    gameBoard.setTexture(e.GetManager().GetImage("t3board.png"));
}
```

So, in theory, my instance of my Engine gets my instance of my ImageManager, which I can use just like if I declared it itself in my board class. But then I get the errors:

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'e'

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'board'

I know this is a lot, but this is my first game and I'm just really lost and tired of never knowing where to put things. Can somebody please tell me how to get this ImageManager working correctly?

Comment: That ImageManager is obsolete. It uses an old version of SFML(pre 2.0). If you don't use the latest version, you should consider updating your version.

Comment: What happens if you comment out all ImageManager references, does the program compile then?

Comment: @Rosme I converted all the outdated functions to sfml 2.1 functions. @user3670482 Yes it does, but I also had to comment out `#include "Engine.h"` at the top of Board.h. Can different files not both include each other?